# Speeding up MySQL Query inc subquery-join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the query below that's pulling data from a number of tables to create an update:

```
UPDATE en_inter.subscribers_data AS sd
inner join en_inter.list_subscribers AS ls on sd.subscriberid = ls.subscriberid 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT pd1.email_address,COUNT(pd1.email_address) AS NumDowns
FROM email.papr_down pd1
INNER JOIN email.papr_data pd2 on pd1.paper_id = pd2.id
INNER JOIN email.papr_subj ps on ps.id = pd2.subject
INNER JOIN email.papr_exam pe on pe.id = pd2.exam
INNER JOIN email.papr_levl pl on pl.id = pd2.level
WHERE pd2.exam = 1
and pd2.level = 4
GROUP BY email_address
) AS downs ON downs.email_address = ls.emailaddress
SET sd.data = ifnull(downs.NumDowns,1)
WHERE sd.fieldid = 33;
```

It works fine but when there are plenty of records in papr_down then it takes ages to process. Any ideas about how it can be optimized?

Comment: http://s22.postimg.org/icqwci2jl/screeny.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the join between the emailAddress is the issue here, you can try out with the join with the Id's.
If you provide us the screen shot of the below query ::

```
EXPLAIN Select * from 
en_inter.subscribers_data AS sd
inner join en_inter.list_subscribers AS ls on sd.subscriberid = ls.subscriberid 

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT pd1.email_address,COUNT(pd1.email_address) AS NumDowns
FROM email.papr_down pd1
INNER JOIN email.papr_data pd2 on pd1.paper_id = pd2.id
INNER JOIN email.papr_subj ps on ps.id = pd2.subject
INNER JOIN email.papr_exam pe on pe.id = pd2.exam
INNER JOIN email.papr_levl pl on pl.id = pd2.level
WHERE pd2.exam = 1
and pd2.level = 4
GROUP BY email_address
) AS downs ON downs.email_address = ls.emailaddress
WHERE sd.fieldid = 33
```

Comment: Ok, here's the screenshot - [link]http://s22.postimg.org/icqwci2jl/screeny.jpg[/link]

Comment: btw yes it is where the email join is, the server returns the select in < 1s

Comment: The link to the screenshot is not accessible from my system, it will be better if you can paste the screenshot along with the question

Comment: It's too long for the comment box so I'll post the screenshot again.

Answer (score 0):

As I know we should use joins only for the columns which are preset in `SELECT` clause and for other joins we should implement using `WHERE` clause

Please try following query:

```
UPDATE en_inter.subscribers_data AS sd
inner join en_inter.list_subscribers AS ls 
on sd.subscriberid = ls.subscriberid 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT pd1.email_address,COUNT(pd1.email_address) AS NumDowns
FROM email.papr_down AS pd1
INNER JOIN email.papr_data AS pd2 on pd1.paper_id = pd2.id
WHERE 
email.papr_exam.id in (select exam from email.papr_data where exam = 1)
AND
email.papr_levl.id in (select level from email.papr_data where level = 4 )
AND 
email.papr_subj.id in (select subject from email.papr_data)

GROUP BY email_address
) AS downs ON downs.email_address = ls.emailaddress
SET sd.data = ifnull(downs.NumDowns,1)
WHERE sd.fieldid = 33;
```

I can not execute this at my machine since i don't have the schema